# why is sql in oledb there is no record in datagridview MS Access database in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

why is sql in oledb there are no records in the datagridview MS Access database in VB.NET whereas if I look directly at MS access the records appear attached screenshot below. Whereas if I do the population query1 and query3 then it shows records in datagridview is there any sql that doesn't fit in query2 according to oledb vb.net.

Thanks

SQLView Query2 in access

```
SELECT EmpID, [Name], TotalCPI, RangeSalary
FROM Query1 AS E INNER JOIN (SELECT Left(RangeCPI,3) AS Start, Mid(RangeCPI,5,3) + 1 AS [End], RangeSalary 
     FROM tblPayrollDecision)  AS PD ON (E.TotalCPI < PD.End) AND (E.TotalCPI >= PD.Start);
```

result query2 in ms access

[image: result query2 in ms access]

```
Public Sub filltable(ByVal dtgrd As Object, ByVal design As String)
        Dim publictable As New DataTable
        Try
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(publictable)
            dtgrd.DataSource = publictable
            Select Case design
                Case "EmpInfo"
                    dtgrd.Columns(0).Visible = False
            End Select
            da.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        End Try
    End Sub
Public Sub jokenselect(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        End Try
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
    End Sub
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 jokenselect("Select * From Query2")
   filltable(DataGridView1, "EmpPic")
    End Sub
```

result query2 in datagridview is no record

[image: result query2 in datagridview is no record]

result from @JoelCoehoorn

[image: result from @JoelCoehoorn]

Comment: I don't know if that's the reason, but ```Mid()``` (Mid(RangeCPI,5,3)) is not a SQL function, but an Access/VBA function, which Access' own query engine does understand, but perhaps the .NET OleDb provider can't handle. The equivalent SQL function is [SUBSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Sub `jokenselect` doesn't execute any SQL command. It also disposes a `da` which it never creates. It is hard to understand how this should work. How is this Sub related to `filltable`?

Comment: Your code makes little sense and your question is incomplete. You pass a query into `jokenselect` that you never use and you haven't bothered to show us the `filltable` method, which appears to be where the actual problem would be.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , sorry, my filltable function or method has been updated in the post

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes , sorry, my filltable function or method has been updated in the post

Comment: @HelO'Ween , 
you are right in that it is a problem with functions implemented in access as opposed to .net oledb. Maybe you can guide me so I can do in sql in .net oledb

Comment: My advice is to use [Dapper](https://www.learndapper.com/) instead of messing around with SqlCommands, SqlReaders, DataTables and so on. Dapper is fast and requires a little fraction of code compared to ADO.Net (your current approach). To more advances programmers, I would suggest [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/).

Comment: Do **NOT** try to re-use the same connection and command objects throughout your application like this. It interferes with an ADO.Net feature called "Connection Pooling" that makes things _slower_, and will cause bottlenecks. **NEVER** manually call `Dispose()`. Instead, create the object to be disposed as part of a `Using` block. Finally, the `jokenselect()` method will force you to write queries that are **unsafe**, and crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection issues. You _NEED_ a way to pass query parameter data to the method separate from the command text.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is this line in the `jokenselect()` method:

```
da.Dispose()
```

*You cannot use an object again once you Dispose() it.* That means the DataAdapter is invalid when later calling `filltable()`.

But the larger issue is this whole data access pattern is **broken** in several important ways:

- Do **NOT** try to re-use the same connection and command objects throughout your application like this. It interferes with an ADO.Net feature called "Connection Pooling" such that it makes things *slower*, and will lead to performance bottlenecks.
- **NEVER** manually call `Dispose()`. Instead, create the object to be disposed as part of a `Using` block. Plan for these objects to be *short-lived*.
- Don't just have a method where you can pass an SQL string by itself. It will force you to write queries in ways that are highly **unsafe**, and crazy-vulnerable to SQL injection issues. You *NEED* a way to pass query parameter data to the method separate from the command text. Escaping single quotes is *NOT* good enough.
- Don't set form elements directly from the data methods. Accept your query inputs (plural), and return the data as a value. Then, let the UI event methods accept these results and use them to update things like DataGrids.

There are a number of ways you can address these issues. One better example pattern (definitely not the only possible good pattern) for data access looks like this:

```
Public Module DB
    Private connectionString As String = "connection string here"

    ' Note this is PRIVATE, so you can't call it directly
    ' from outside the module. Instead, add a public
    ' method for each query you need to run.
    ' As the program grows, you can also expand this Module
    ' to it's own namespace or class library project, with 
    ' different logical areas having their own Friend modules.
    Private Function GetData(SQL As String, addParams As Action(Of OleDbParameterCollection) As DataTable
        Dim result As New DataTable

        Using cn  As New OleDbConnection(connectionString), _
              cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, cn), 
              da  As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            If addParams IsNot Nothing Then addParams(cmd.Parameters)
            da.Fill(result)
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function RunQuery2() As DataTable
        Return GetData("SELECT * FROM Query2", Nothing)
    End Function

    ' Extra method to show an example using the addParams() argument
    Public Function GetEmployeeByID(EmplID As Integer) As DataTable
        Return GetData("SELECT * FROM Query2 WHERE EmpID = ?", 
            Sub(p) p.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = EmplID)
    End Function
End Module
```

And now the `Form_Load()` method would look like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try 'Notice all the error handling now also lives at the UI layer
        dtgrd.DataSource = DB.RunQuery2()
        dtgrd.Columns(0).Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but `Public Function RunQuery2() As DataTable Return GetData("SELECT * FROM Query2", Nothing) End Sub` error end function expected and `da As New OleDbDataAdapater(cmd)` there was a typo and `If addParams IsNot Nothing Then addParams()`  error Argument not specified for parameter 'obj' of 'Action(Of OleDbParameterCollection)'

Comment: @mbmt Fixed a couple typos. Should be better now. That's a hazard of typing code direct into the reply window, without intellisense, compiler, or debugger support.

Comment: I have updated according to your answer, but the result is no record. you can see the screenshot that I posted

Answer (score 0):

```
There are some issues in your code placement - If they are fixed then issue will be resolved
//Kindly note Data source needs to be assigned first before the fill is hit and binded
 dtgrd.DataSource = publictable
            da.Fill(publictable)           
//Dispose should be usually done in finally block 
            da.Dispose()
//Connection objects are created in one and used in another block
 da.Dispose() and con.Open()  and close() is hit in the jokenselect
whereas the object da is being used in the filltable block
Either create one functional block and write the logic so that the created object da is called first and then disposed later
As the provided code in question gives Object reference issue and hence empty records.
```